# looping through array not working

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to get the value of `fields` object in the array `o` . I'm not able to get the value inside the property. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var o = {
  "templatename": "sdgds",
  "fields": {
    "s1_req_1": 1,
    "s1_req_2": 1,
    "s1_req_3": 1,
    "s1_req_4": 1,
    "s1_req_5": 1,
    "s1_req_6": 1,
    "s1_req_7": 1,
    "s1_req_8": 1,
    "s1_req_9": 1,
    "s1_req_10": 1,
    "s1_req_11": 1,
    "s1_req_12": 1,
    "s1_req_13": 1,
    "s1_req_14": 1,
    "v1_dm_1": 1,
    "v1_dm_5": 1,
    "v1_dm_6": 1,
    "f1_fs_3": 1,
    "f1_fs_1": 1,
    "f1_fs_2": 1,
    "e3_eh_19": 1,
    "f1_fs_11": 1,
    "s3_sh_1": 1,
    "s3_sh_6": 1,
    "s3_sh_7": 1,
    "v1_dm_7": 1,
    "v1_dm_13": 1,
    "v1_dm_9": 1
  },
  "customerid": 'SMRTsspd'
};

$('#template').val(o.templatename);
$(o.fields).each(function(t) {
  $('input[value=' + t.name + ']').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what is `t.name`? and from where it's coming from. And which value you are trying to fetch?

Comment: `o` and `o.field` aren't arrays - they're objects

Comment: `$.each` works also with objects: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: thanks for the informations @Rory McCrossan & Martin Adamek. Can you guys post answers related to my question. i just wanna explore various options.

Comment: I already did, with both vanilla JS & jquery examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through object without jquery:

```
Object.keys(o.fields).forEach(function (key) {
    $('input[value=' + key + ']').prop('checked', o.fields[key]);
});
```

As others have said, `o.fields` is an object, so to iterate through its values, you need to extract its keys first, via `Object.keys(o.fields)` method. Then you can iterate through those keys via simple `Array.forEach(keys)`. Finally to use the value, you can just do `o.fields[key]`.

Or with jquery, use it like this:

```
$.each(o.fields, function(key, value) {
    $('input[value=' + key + ']').prop('checked', value);
});
```

Comment: Nice work. the code works. Can you explain the code a little bit?

Comment: aah sry, will fix it

Comment: jquery example fixed

Answer (score 1):

Use **For-In**
You can use a For-In loop to enumerate through an object to get each key value pair.

```
for(var key in o.fields){
  if (o.fields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    $('input[value=' + key + ']').prop('checked', true);
  }
}
```

```js
var o = {
  "templatename": "sdgds",
  "fields": {
    "s1_req_1": 1,
    "s1_req_2": 1,
    "s1_req_3": 1,
    "s1_req_4": 1,
    "s1_req_5": 1,
    "s1_req_6": 1,
    "s1_req_7": 1,
    "s1_req_8": 1,
    "s1_req_9": 1,
    "s1_req_10": 1,
    "s1_req_11": 1,
    "s1_req_12": 1,
    "s1_req_13": 1,
    "s1_req_14": 1,
    "v1_dm_1": 1,
    "v1_dm_5": 1,
    "v1_dm_6": 1,
    "f1_fs_3": 1,
    "f1_fs_1": 1,
    "f1_fs_2": 1,
    "e3_eh_19": 1,
    "f1_fs_11": 1,
    "s3_sh_1": 1,
    "s3_sh_6": 1,
    "s3_sh_7": 1,
    "v1_dm_7": 1,
    "v1_dm_13": 1,
    "v1_dm_9": 1
  },
  "customerid": 'SMRTsspd'
};

$('#template').val(o.templatename);
for (var key in o.fields) {
  if (o.fields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    $('input[value=' + key + ']').prop('checked', true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='checkbox' value='s1_req_1'>
<input type='checkbox' value='s1_req_2'>
<input type='checkbox' value='s1_req_3'>
<input type='checkbox' value=''>
<input type='checkbox' value=''>
```

Comment: I was looking for a jquery solution. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Thanks! Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Since, the post tag is `jquery` ,I'm giving a jQuery specific solution specifically `$.each`.

For Vanilla JS solutions, look at SO Post: [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

```js
var o = {
  "templatename": "sdgds",
  "fields": {
    "s1_req_1": 1,
    "s1_req_2": 1,
    "s1_req_3": 1,
    "s1_req_4": 1,
    "s1_req_5": 1,
    "s1_req_6": 1,
    "s1_req_7": 1,
    "s1_req_8": 1,
    "s1_req_9": 1,
    "s1_req_10": 1,
    "s1_req_11": 1,
    "s1_req_12": 1,
    "s1_req_13": 1,
    "s1_req_14": 1,
    "v1_dm_1": 1,
    "v1_dm_5": 1,
    "v1_dm_6": 1,
    "f1_fs_3": 1,
    "f1_fs_1": 1,
    "f1_fs_2": 1,
    "e3_eh_19": 1,
    "f1_fs_11": 1,
    "s3_sh_1": 1,
    "s3_sh_6": 1,
    "s3_sh_7": 1,
    "v1_dm_7": 1,
    "v1_dm_13": 1,
    "v1_dm_9": 1
  },
  "customerid": 'SMRTsspd'
};

$('#template').val(o.templatename);
$.each(o.fields, function(key, value) {
  console.log(key + ":" + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not get you. From what i have understood.

$(o.fields) does not make any sense.

o.fields should be an array in order to use each.
try changing the code to

```
"fields": [
    {"s1_req_1": 1}
    {"s1_req_2": 1},
    ......]
```

and as for 'name' there is no key as name.

o.fields.each(function(t){

});

Can you post the full code.